# F5 BIG-IP monitor to detect http to https redirects

Tags: https, redirect, http, f5-big-ip

We have an F5 BIG-IP load-balancer we use in front of a web application hosted by several identical servers. The application listens on port 443 for SSL/TLS requests and port 80 for http requests. However, the *only* thing that happens to an http port 80 request is that it gets a 302 redirect response.

I am trying to create a monitor for the F5 pool used for port 80 that detects that the service is working properly, i.e., that http requests get redirected to https. However, I cannot find a monitor to do this.

Is there such a monitor?

Comment: Let the F5, rather than the back end servers, perform the http to https redirect and you won’t need the http pool at all (and no monitoring either)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check that a redirect happens, create a monitor of type HTTP, set the send string to `GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n` and the receive string to `302 Found`.

As far as I can tell, the HTTP monitor type adds a single `\r\n` because it intends to work with HTTP 0.9, but there's no way to send a redirect in HTTP 0.9, so you have to use 1.0, which requires another `\r\n`.

To check the destination, try a receive string of `Location: https://`, possibly with the specific hostname you're interested in appended.

Comment: That worked (although in my case I had to change `302 Found` to `HTTP/1.1 302`).